# CSS div fill entire parent without position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I have some divs that are laid out in a tabular manner using table CSS. Each of the cells has a child. I need this child to fill the height of the parent.

I cannot use position:absolute because it will ruin the layout of the rest of the site. Example HTML is:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="data">
            sasfadasd
            aasdfa
            asdfasdf
            asdf
        </div>
   </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="data">
            sasfadasd
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="data">
            sasfadasd
            aasdfa
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

using the following CSS

```
#parent{
    display:table;
    width:200px;
}
.item{
    display:table-cell;
    padding:5px;
}
.data{
    background-color:grey;
}
```

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/dPw7W/

I want all the grey boxes to be the same size. coloring the parents grey is cheating

**Edit**
 Parent height is not able to be set. It is dynamically populated by the child elements. the data div **only** exists so that i can space the divs. If i use the border-spacing, it won't let me dynamically set spacing. If someone can suggest how to space the cells without border spacing, that would solve the problem.

Comment: Do you want to achieve this through pure CSS, or by any means necessary (JavaScript)?

Comment: Can you change your markup? If yes, could you remove the `.item` divs?

Comment: CSS is preferable. If no solution is available, i will go JS, but i would really rather not

Comment: @melhosseiny: The required result is a table with 3 equal cells. However, i need to space them dynamically, i cant use the `border-spacing` attribute as that only has options to space them all equally. If you can find a way to space them dynamically without border spacing then the `.item` divs can go

Comment: @DavidColwell, I edited my answer, adding a JS/jquery-based solution

Comment: @DavidColwell Are you opposed to spacing using white borders?

Comment: @melhosseiny: I prefer transparent, but can deal with white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="items">
  <div class="item">
    sasfadasd
    aasdfa
    asdfasdf
    asdf
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    sasfadasd
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   sasfadasd
   aasdfa
  </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#items {
  display:table;
  width:200px;
}  

.item {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color:grey;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPw7W/13/) (Tested in Chrome only).

Comment: I like this solution, its so simple leaves me thinking why wasnt it workable though

Comment: @skv Table cells in the same row have equal height but their children don't so removing the child `.data` div is all that is required.

Comment: I agree but surprised that the OP has not responded, will wait

Comment: This solution works. The issue that i have is i do not want white borders, however, as i failed to specify this in the OP, this is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

For the `div`s to fill the height through `height: 100%`, the parent needs a height defined. See http://jsfiddle.net/dPw7W/3/

```
.item{
    display:table-cell;
    padding:5px;
    height: 100px;
}
.data{
    background-color:grey;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Since fixed heights in the CSS are not an option, here's a jquery-based solution. Please note that it sets fixed heights, but based on the largest div. (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dPw7W/9/)

```
// When document.ready fires
$(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0, height;

    // Loop over all divs with css class 'data'
    $('.data').each(function() {
        if ((height = $(this).height()) > maxHeight) {
            // Store highest width of them all in a variable
            maxHeight = height;
        }
    })

    // Set all '.data'-divs to the same height.
    $('.data').height(maxHeight);
});
```

Comment: Updated. Cant set parent height.

Comment: Too overpowered for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

make this give `min-height`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dPw7W/1/)**

```
.data{
   background-color:grey;
    min-height:300px;

}
```

Comment: I was looking for it to dynamically change the height based on the largest element (hence the table cells). If you can suggest a way to do this while maintaining the spacing between the cells... but i cant use fixed heights

Answer (score 0):

```
.data{
    background-color:grey;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in all common browsers, neigher IE10 nor Firefox do it as indended.

Comment: I have checked it on Chrome, but it don't have fixed length.

Comment: And where you saw here that Parent have setted height?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. Add `height: 100%` to all your elements. This will keep everything dynamic.

```
#parent{
    display:table;
    width:200px;
    height: 100%;
}
.item{
    display:table-cell;
    padding:5px;
    height: 100%; /* Not neccessary */
}
.data{
    background-color:grey;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dPw7W/5/

Comment: The problem with `height: 100%` is, there must be a height set on the parent element. If `position: absolute` is no option and `height: 100%` is apparently neither, it seems like there is no clean solution available.

Answer (score 0):

give a static height to your data class

```
 .data{
    background-color:grey;
    height : 100px;
  }
```